# Modifying the name of an instance variable

Tags: ruby

Let's say I have @chicken, but I would like to rename it to @chicken1, and @chicken2 via a count loop. Once I have generated the name with something like `"chicken#{@count}"` how do I then turn the output into something like @chicken1, etc?

Comment: It can be done, but why do you want this? Sounds like you should use an array instead.

Comment: Well, basically I am generating google maps and it would be too complicated for me to do an array for all the data that needs to be pushed in.

Comment: Actually, I clicked the tick prematurely below.. it wasn't really what I was looking for.. all I really wanted was to be able to create a new instance variable using a count.. or even a random number like "@x#{rand()}"

Comment: It ended up not being an issue though because I was able to rename my google map div id (using a count), which turned out to be the cause of my issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby has method [remove_instance_variable](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/remove_instance_variable) for such a task

```
class A
  def initialize
    @chicken = 'chichen'
  end

  def rename
    count = 1
    instance_variable_set(:"@chicken#{count}", @chicken)
  end

  def remove
    remove_instance_variable(:@chicken)
  end
end

a = A.new

a.instance_variables #=> [:@chicken]

a.rename

a.instance_variables #=> [:@chicken, :@chicken1]

a.remove

a.instance_variables #=> [:@chicken1]

a.instance_variable_get("@chicken1") #=> "chicken"
```

Comment: Please, don't use `eval` unless it is *absolutely* unavoidable. `instance_variable_set` will do just fine here.